# Windows Server file access and deletion logging?

Tags: windows-server-2008, logging

I'm looking to log all file access (reads, writes, creations, deletions) including usernames and times for a specific folder that is being accessed via a network share.

Using Windows Server 2008. Freeware would be ideal, but I would consider paying if it had the features I want.

Any recommendations for software?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't specified what features you want (other than the ability to log) so if you want free, you got free. Enable auditing in W2K8 (Audit object access) on the GPO that applies to the server where the share is and then add auditing entries on the shared folder in question. Every access of files or folders (Read, Write, etc) in the share will be written to the event log.